# How to center text vertically in Bootstrap's navbar-brand class?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a logo with some text. I want the text to be vertically aligned to the middle.

```
<a class="navbar-brand" href="foo"><img src="bar"/>FooBar</a>
```

`navbar-brand` is defined in Bootstrap like that:

```
.navbar-brand {
  float: left;
  height: 50px;
  padding: 15px 15px;
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 20px;
}
```

I've tried wrapping image together with text in span and set its style as follows:

```
vertical-align: middle; 
display: inline-block;
```

[See JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/25b9vf47/1/)

Could someone give me a hint, how should I center the text vertically?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use following css:

```
#foo {
    align-items: center;
    display: flex;
}
```

Use `display:flex` instead of `display:inline-block`.

**[Working Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/25b9vf47/4/)**

Answer (score 1):

If cross browser compatibility is a must for older browsers the display table approach might be worth looking at. Really liking the answer from Ketan though.

All that would be required is an additional tag around the text like so:

**HTML:**

```
<span id="foo">
      <img src="http://radiofair.eu/downloads/images/foobar.png"/>      
  <span>FooBar</span>
</span>
```

**CSS:**

```
#foo{
  display: table;
  color: red;  
}

#foo span{ 
  display:table-cell;
  vertical-align:middle;
}
```

[Working Example](https://jsfiddle.net/25b9vf47/5/)